# EXP4J: can't get a good factorial operator working

Tags: java, android, parsing

I have the following factorial operator declared:

```
Operator factorial = new Operator("!", 1, true, Operator.PRECEDENCE_POWER + 1) {
  @Override public double apply(double... args) {
    final long arg = (long) args[0];
    if ((double) arg != args[0]) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operand for factorial has to be an integer");
    }
    if (arg < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The operand of the factorial can not " +
      "be " +
      "less than zero");
    }
    double result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= arg; i++) {
      result *= i;
    }
    return result;
  }
};
```

So, it works fine when you have simple expressions such as `5!` and so on, but things start to break when you try to emulate normal calculator behavior. The following example throws an `IllegalArgumentException()`:

`5!+5`

Why? I guess it has something to do with 2 adjacent operators or something, since using `(5!)+5` works with no issues.

This is devastating for the project I'm working on. Someone has suggested converting the operator into a function but that would take too much time. I've tried changing all the constructor parameters but none of them changed the problem.

Comment: Opened this issue: https://github.com/fasseg/exp4j/issues/62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround that will make the factorial behave as intended. The trick is to add a second variable and make the factorial a pseudo unrary operator, so:

Instead of: `5!+5` I used: `5!(1)+5`. This required no refactoring in my program, as the only change made was the way the operator was being inputted.

This way, the parser works wonderfully. You also need to change the actual `Operator` declaration to this:

```
Operator factorial = new Operator("!", 2, true, Operator.PRECEDENCE_POWER + 1) {
  @Override public double apply(double... args) {
    final long arg = (long) args[0];
    if ((double) arg != args[0]) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operand for factorial has to be an integer");
    }
    if (arg < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The operand of the factorial can not " +
      "be " +
      "less than zero");
    }
    double result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= arg; i++) {
      result *= i;
    }
    return result;
  }
};
```

I suppose one should avoid using unary operators altogether when using EXP4J.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly has to do with there being two operators in a row.

Or, alternatively, it has to do with EXP4J being a poor implementation of an expression parser.

Anyway you look at it, there is no simple solution using EXP4J. It is simply not up to the task of handling postfix operators. (If you were prepared to use `!5` to mean "5 factorial", there wouldn't be a problem; just make sure that you give it the same precedence as the other unary prefix operators. But the fact that you don't want to use a function suggests that you don't want to change the syntax of `!` either.)

The big hint is that the `Operator` constructor does not have any way to specify whether an operator is prefix or postfix. (`!` is a *postfix* operator, because it follows its operand, unlike, say, unary `-` with is prefix.)

If the expression parser doesn't know, it certainly cannot validate the input, and there's good reason to believe that it can't accurately parse it either. [Note 1] Another hint is that custom operators need to be declared as taking 1 or 2 operands, which means that a custom operator cannot act like `-` which has both prefix and infix syntax.

The special-case hack for unary `+` and `-` operators interacts badly with the hack which doesn't attempt to check whether a unary operator is prefix or postfix. In `5!+5`, the `+` immediately follows an operator, which EXP4J interprets as indicating that the `+` is a prefix unary `+`. So it parses that almost as if it were `(5!)(+5)` except that it does not insert the implicit multiplication that it would insert if you actually wrote `(5!)(+5)`.

So you get the exception, because you can't have two value side-by-side without an operator between them.

Actually fixing this would require quite a bit of rewriting. You might well be better off using a different expression evaluator, or throwing your own together with a standard parser generator.

Comment: After a lot of messing around, I found a workaround that is a little easier than rewriting all my program with another expression parser. See my answer.